# How to Add Items in Combobox Efficiently in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am a C++ developer and have recently started learning WPF. I am working on a wpf app where I am using MVVM. I have comboboxes and I need to add items in it. Although I generally use ComboboxPropertyName.Add("") to add items in it, I am looking for an efficient method which adds the items without much code length. Here is the code:

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding BoardBoxList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBoardBoxList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Name="comboBox2" />
```

**ViewModel Class:**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> BoardBoxList
    {
        get { return _BoardBoxList; }
        set
        {
            _BoardBoxList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BoardBoxList");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// _SelectedBoardBoxList
    /// </summary>
    private string _SelectedBoardBoxList;
    public string SelectedBoardBoxList
    {
        get { return _SelectedBoardBoxList; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedBoardBoxList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBoardBoxList");
        }
    }
```

Here Is how I had added items in my combobox in C++:

```
static const signed char boards[][9] = {
{},                                           // left blank to indicate no selection
{ 'S', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '2', 0 },   // redhook
{ 'S', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '8', 0 },   // bavaria
{ 'S', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '2', '0', 0 },   // flying dog
};

m_boardBox = new ComboBox(String::empty);
for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    m_boardBox->addItem(String((char*)(boards[i])), i); 
m_boardBox->setSelectedId(2); // select Bavaria by default
addAndMakeVisible(m_boardBox);
```

If you notice above, you will find the loop adding items easily. This is how i wanna add items to my combobox.

If I use `_BoardBoxList.Add("....");` I will have to use many .Adds. Is their an efficient way where I can store the items in a list/collection and add them into the combobox in the form of `for loop` just like above?

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a constructor of ObservableCollection that can consume an enumerable as a start set.

```
new ObservableCollection<string>(boards);
```

Boards would have to be an collection of strings not chars.

Edit:

```
var boards = new[]{ "S1010012" ,   // redhook
                   "S1010018",   // bavaria
                   "S1010020"    // flying dog
                  }
```

Comment: Well using ObservableCollection seems to be a good approach but how would you ideally add the `board` items in collection of strings? :) Can you elaborate it with a code pls :)

Comment: @StonedJesus I don't quite understand your problem but see my edit if it helps.

Comment: Can `var boards = new[] { };` be created outside constructor. I need to access `boards` in my method and since its in constructor, it throws an error that boards not present in this context.

Comment: You can crate class field and use it in other methods. Or static class with `public static readolny` field (as this looks like a constant) and you can use it throughout program your.

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing stopping you from using the very same loop in C# to add items to the observable collection, the `ComboBox` will update automatically. Unless you are more specific about your problem there is nothing else to say.

The goal of the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property is that you do not imperatively add items to the `ComboBox` itself via a loop but just specify a collection and the control will take care of the rest, how the items get into the collection if your business.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you can use `AddRange` Method of the `List` class

you can create list (add use AddRange - for adding, for loop, etc.), and than create Observable Collection based on that list.

```
ObservableCollection<string> collection 
                 = new ObservableCollection<string>(myList);
```

And than you can bind observable to `ItemSource`, if you need it (updating), otherwise you can bind list.

Comment: i have not used AddRange till now. Have a look at my xaml combobox binding and the property I have set. Keeping that in mind what would be the idea way of adding the items present in `board`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` property. If you use an `ObservableCollection` as the source, you can forget updating the items manually and just work with the list in the view model.

Comment: Well you are right......using ObservableCollection seems to be a good approach but how would you ideally add the board items in collection of strings? :) Can you elaborate it with a code pls :)